# Automatically set custom taxonomy to custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy-terms

I have a Custom Post Type `property` and Custom Taxonomies as `city` and `state`. This is not hierarchical taxonomies, but they already has relationships (each city marked with it's state). I want to set state automatically that depends of the chosen city. What action or function can help?

I tried to use `add_action( 'save_post', 'save_property_meta' );` with `wp_set_object_terms`, but I don't know how to write a condition.

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_property_meta' );
function save_property_meta( $post_id ) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property_city' ); 
    if( $terms ){
        $term = array_shift( $terms );
        $term->id;
    } 
    /** It's should be condition**/ 
    wp_set_object_terms( get_the_ID(), get_term_meta( $city_term['id'], 'property_city_county'), true);
}
```

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: You can add the code by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54369751/edit) your question.

Comment: @Kashif Rafique thank you, I added